# 'End(xlDown)' acting weird

Tags: vba, excel, row, offset

I suspect that the `.end(xlDown)` is acting a bit weird.

```
Dim rfound As Range

Set rfound = Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Me.ComboBox1.Value, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), _
ComboBox1.Value) > 0 And rfound.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
rfound.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value
```

Upon `CommandButton1_click`, the code will search in the column B for any matched criteria and then `OffSet` to the right cell  provided my conditions are all met. However, it prompt me a message `Run-time error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error`.

I have no clue where is the problem. For illustration:

[image]

Comment: Please give me a moment to consider the answers. Thank you.

Comment: By using .end(xlUp), refer to my last image above, if I want to insert 'Product' and 'Description' into 'Company A', it is not achievable.

Comment: Well you edited your question after we had pointed out what was wrong with your code - we can hardly guess you were going to modify beforehand. If you expect ongoing assistance then I think its reasonable that you treat those who help you appropriately.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have edit my question so eagerly. I will change back my question to the state where it is left without edit. Yes indeed I should revise myself when asking any question, thanks for the reminding @brettdj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your current code

1. Presumably finds `B2` as `rfound`  *(Note: It would be better to test if `rfound` exists after the `Find` with `If Not rfound Is Nothing Then)*
2. Then `C2` is  `rfound.Offset(0, 1)`
3. `rfound.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown)` find the last cell in column C as all other cells are blank
4. `rfound.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` tries to enter a value in the cell one row below the very last row - no can do.

Look up from the bottom instead, ie rather than

`Then rfound.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value`
use
`Then Cells(Rows.Count, rfound.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = TextBox1.Value`

Comment: Do you have time to look at this issue in depth? I may post my code here if you want. Thank you.

Comment: Yes Sir, I did. But there is another part of my code that will insert another NEW data into column B,C and D that uses `.end(xlUp)`.

Answer (score 1):

My three cents...

The beauty is not in writing complex codes but breaking it up in easy to understand lines so that it is easier to understand what the code does. Also it helps in debugging it if an error occurs...

1. You already know that you have to write to Col C so why make it more complex by using `Offset`
2. Test if `rfound` exists as brettdj suggested
3. Use `xlUp` to find the last row.

See this example. (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rfound As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rfound = .Columns(2).Find(What:=Me.ComboBox1.Value, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
            If ComboBox1.Value <> "" And _
            WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), ComboBox1.Value) > 0 And _
            rfound.Offset(, 1).Value <> "" Then

                '~~> Find the next available row in Col C
                lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                '~~> Directly write to the cell
                .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = TextBox1.Value
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` will look for the last cell before blank in that column. Which I do not want this to happen.

Comment: In that case, you can use `xlDown` but ensure that you do a proper error handling to check if you have not reached the end of rows which is what is happening at the moment. :)

Comment: Yes in the end I did manage to solve my problems thanks to all the ideas given by you all. Once again thank you very much!